# Details on Mamba?

Tags: sidechains

I've heard Charles mention that Mamba is being actively worked on and might be released in 2022 but I haven't been able to find much information about it.

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/rascmq/update_on_iele_from_ama/) suggests that Mamba will be powered by IELE. [This blog post](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2022/01/14/how-we-re-scaling-cardano-in-2022/) by IOHK suggests that Mamba is in the 2022 roadmap.

Where can I learn more about Mamba? Do they have documentation similar to [Milkomeda](https://dcspark.gitbook.io/milkomeda)? I've tried searching for this information but haven't been successful (maybe I have searched hard enough?).

Answer (score 2):

Was just recently mentioned in one of the videos, made by Charles:
https://youtu.be/H9wAyW_EcDA?t=484

Comment: looking forward to the blog post he said they'll be releasing!